# android play-services-gcm in android studio not recgnized

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I downloaded and installed the

> "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+"

from the sdk-manager but when i try to import google gcm sample in android studio and build the project, the error blow is shown:

> "Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+"

However when i try to download "Repository and sync project" the sdk-manager says: "There is nothing to install or update".

What i must to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the dependency to your app-module´s gradle file...

```
dependencies { 
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
}
```

... and run Gradle-sync. Gradle build system then will download the library and the error should not occur.
Refer to the [How-To-Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

don't use idk-manager for this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

Add above line in your **dependencies**